# Recover a SVN repository from within a SVN repository

Tags: svn

OK - so I managed to create a SVN repository within another SVN repository on a remote network svn server. See screenshots for details. I used the Tortoise client when I originally made that fatal error. Bottom line, I just need to pull the data off of the existing repository and place it into the first/original repository.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. *Export* the outer repository (exporting prevents the creation of `.svn` folders) into some folder on your HD. (If it is too big to be exported all, you need to selectively export only the files and folders of the inner repository.) Recover the inner repository from that, and move it wherever you need it, trash the rest of the exported files and folders.
2. Make sure the inner repository you salvaged is working faultlessly.
3. Delete (`svn delete`) the files and folders of the inner repository from the outer one.

Yes, that leaves you with a confusing piece of history in the outer repository, but usually this is not a problem. (There are ways to remove stuff from a repository's history, but that is complicated and rarely ever worth the bother.)